# With Ubuntu 20.04, my machine is turned off, except that it isn't really off

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, acpi

I’ve had my general purpose (e-mail/browser) desktop PC for about 10 years. I bought it with Windows Vista installed. As that OS is not supported by many applications, I decided to switch it to Ubuntu 20.04.1. Taking advantage of the low price and ready availability of older technology components, I added more memory and an extra 500Gb SATA hard drive, on which I installed Ubuntu as the only OS. The other disk can be selected as a boot option for Vista and as it’s FAT32 I can see any document or jpg photo scan that I’m interested in when I’m in the default Ubuntu OS. All is well with the new setup bit there is one conundrum that puzzles me.

The machine is an Advent QC5003 with an Intel® Desktop Board DG45ID  motherboard.  The BIOS is version IDG4511H.86A.0090.2008.0924.1800. There is an option to wake on LAN from S5 to ‘power on’ or ‘stay off’. It has always been set to the ‘power on’ option, which I was unaware of, and consequently has never  been used. There is little point in my having such a facility on a mains-powered desktop machine.

I have put a Google Play ‘wake on Lan’ utility on my tablet and am very surprised that after I have turned the desktop machine off with the icon on the home screen, it still wakes when instructed to do so from the tablet. If I boot into Vista and turn the PC off with the Windows icon, it doesn’t wake when an instruction is sent from the tablet.

Below is a table cut from the motherboard’s manual.
[image]

I would really like someone to explain this behaviour to me. It’s almost like there is a 4 and a half state in the hardware of my machine.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you right. Is that not the expected behavior in S5?

Comment: At S5, the machine *seems* off to all human senses, but a trickle is keeping the BIOS wake-up logic alive. This usually powers the BIOS features for Wake-On-LAN and Boot-on-schedule. To reach G3, physically disconnect the power.

Comment: Why then does powering off in Windows mean that it can't be woken, whereas in Linux it can? What is the difference between the two states that the hardware is in?